# Assistance with scripting

Tags: regex, svn, awk

I have this script:

```
svn log -q | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" <"$2"xyz.com"">"}' | sort -u > authors-test.txt
```

It collects author names from SVN repo and changes them to this format.

```
himanshu.khanna = himanshu.khanna (himanshu.khanna@xyz.com)
```

I want to remove (`.`) from first name and last name after `=`

That is i want result this:

```
himanshu.khanna = himanshu khanna (himanshu.khanna@xyz.com)
```

I would really appreciate if anyone helps me out and modify this script or provide a different one that gives desired results.

Comment: Your sample input bears little resemblance to your script. For example it neither starts with `r` nor contains `|`. Rather than trying to help you implement a script that is probably the wrong approach - post some real sample input and expected output and we can help you. Do you REALLY need the output sorted or is the `sort -u` just to get you a unique list (you do not need to pipe to `sort` to do the latter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sub()` to replace the `.` with a space. You'll need to copy `$2` into another variable, because you don't want to replace it in all the places that you use it.

You also need to escape the `.`, because it's a special character in regular expressions.

```
awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); name=$2; sub(/\./, " ", name); print $2" = "name" <"$2"xyz.com"">"}'
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help, i tried your script giving this error:

**awk: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'**

Giving this result where first letter is missing in name:

anagha.todalbagi =  nagha.todalbagi <anagha.todalbagi@xyz.com>

Comment: Need to double the escape -- once for the string, then for the regexp

Comment: Thanks,am grateful for your assistance. Keep up the good work.

Comment: No, don't double the escape - use the correct delimiters. The first arg for `sub()` is a regexp, not a string, so when you use a string in that context awk has to convert it to a regexp first and THAT is what's using up the backslash and causing you to have to double up on the backslashes so there's one left to be used in the regexp after the string->regexp conversion. Always use `sub(/constant regexp/,"string")`, not `sub("dynamic regexp","string")` unless you have a very specific reason and fully understand the effects/caveats.

Comment: Good point. I always forget that you can use regexp literals in function arguments, not just as tests by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping with sed:

```
echo -e "himanshu.khanna = himanshu.khanna (himanshu.khanna@xyz.com)" | sed 's/\(^.*= \)\(.*\)\(\.\)\(.* \)\(.*$\)/\1\2 \4\5/g'
```

Result:

```
himanshu.khanna = himanshu khanna (himanshu.khanna@xyz.com)
```

Much shorter and cleaner than any awk solution.

Comment: How do I apply this on all author entries in that particular txt file. I'm grepping authors name from a SVN repo as i have to convert svn to git.

Answer (score 0):

The following is essentially the same as @AGuevara's suggestion but (a) adds the `/^r/` specified by the OP; sprinkles in some `" *"` for robustness, and (c) shows how to avoid all the backslash-escapes.
The caveat is that the required flag for extended regular expressions is not universal: I've used -E here but GNU uses -r:

```
sed -E -e '/^r/ s/^ *([^ ]*) *= *(.*)[.](.*)$/\1 = \2 \3/'
```